# How to run clojure on OpenShift

Tags: clojure, openshift, leiningen

I am trying to deploy a Clojure application on OpenShift using the [clojure-cartridge](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/clojure-cartridge) running the following command:

`rhc app create myapp http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/openshift-cartridges/clojure-cartridge`

I can run the application locally using `lein run` and looking at `http://localhost:8080/` It works as expected. But when I run it from OpenShift I get: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

When I do `rhc tail` I get:

`Downloading Leiningen to /var/lib/openshift/54a1a338fcf933fb93000106/clojure//home/self-installs/leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar now...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14.2M  100 14.2M    0     0  18.6M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25.5M
Could not transfer artifact lein-ring:lein-ring:pom:0.7.5 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /.m2/repository/lein-ring/lein-ring/0.7.5
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.`

I am new to both Clojure and using OpenShift, so I could have missed or misunderstood something obvious. But any ideas on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about OpenShift though this error:

```
Specified destination directory cannot be created: /.m2/repository/lein-ring/lein-ring/0.7.5
```

is a strong hint that the `$HOME` environment variable is not available in OpenShift. lein writes files to `$HOME/.m2/repository/...` so if $HOME where unset it would result in the error  above. [It looks like OpenShift allows this:](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#custom-variables)

```
Setting Custom Environment Variables
Set one of more environment variables for an application with the following command:

$  hc env set <Variable>=<Value> <Variable2>=<Value2> -a App_Name
```